# What determines the mosquitto.db file size limit

Tags: mosquitto

I am new to mosquitto and have a few questions I hope you all can help me with:

1. what determines the limit size of the persistence file in mosquitto? Is it the system momory or disk space?
2. What happens when the persistence file gets larger than the limit size? Can I transfer it to another server for temporary storage?
3. How would mosquitto use the transferred file to publish messages when it restarts?

I appreciate any feedback.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably a combination of both Filesystem maximum filesize and system/process memory, which ever is smallest. But I would expect the performance problems that would be apparent before you reached these limits to be a bigger problem.
2. Mosquitto probably crashes. If mossquitto exceeds the system/process memory limits then it's going to get killed by the OS or crash instantly. I doubt there would be any benefit to moving it to a different machine as if mosquitto crashes due to hitting either of those limits the file is likely to be corrupted so unable to be read in even if restarted on the same machine.
3. See answer 2

In reality you should never come close to these limits, having that many inflight messages means there are some very SERIOUS issues with the design of your whole system.